# LCM and GCD of numbers with euclidean algorithm.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I know that given two numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $a=bq+r$ then $(a,r)$ and $(a,b)$ are the same. But I want to know if this is true with the LCM as well. I think this is untrue, because if we let the GCD be equal to $k$, then $\frac{a}{k}$ and $\frac{b}{k}$ must be coprime by the definition of GCD. Then, we know that the LCM of a and b is different to the LCM of a and r because they have different prime factors in them.

Is my reasoning correct? If it is not, what is the correct proof? Please help me.

Comment: What you need is an example, not "reasoning." And it is rather easy to disprove with an example: take $a=2$, $b=3$. Then $q=1$, $r=1$, and $2$ and $1$ do not have the same LCM as $2$ and $3$. Worse if $a$ properly divides $b$; the GCD would be $a$, the LCM is $b$, but $r=0$, and LCM of $a$ and $0$ is $0$.

Comment: It's not even true for gcds. What is true is $\,(a,b) = (r,b)\ \ $

Comment: yeah but the example feels sussy. I wanted to explain why it doesnt work, so I tried to show why in variables. Is my reasining corect?

Comment: What happens when you use your reasoning with Arturo's example of $a$ and $b$?

Comment: After said fix, if you rewrite the lcms as gcds you will see it is true $\iff bq = 0\iff a = r\ \ $

Comment: A universal statement is not disproven by "argument", it is disproven by counterexample. There's nothing "sussy" about an example in that circumstance; to the contrary, it is an unassailable answer and verification. By contrast, your "reasoning"  is suspect because you do not justify your claims about prime factors.

Comment: $\text{lcm}(m,n) = \dfrac{m \times n}{\text{gcd}(m,n)}.~$  Note that in general, if $~a = bq + r,~$ you will **not** have that $~(a \times b) = (a \times r).$